# Spinner and ListView in same activity

Tags: android, listview, focus, spinner

i have a problem which i narrowed it down to a focus problem. At least it seems like a focus problem, i might be wrong.

Declerations:

```
 LogListAdapter adapter;
 Spinner filterTypeMenu;
 ListView list;
```

onCreate:

```
 list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.loglist);
 filterTypeMenu = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 adapter = new LogListAdapter (this, R.layout.row, filteredLogs);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 filterTypeMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); // tried with inner class, same result
```

in my interface method when i complete my process:

```
 ..
 ..
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 ..
 ..
```

and click listeners:

```
        @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(position),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

My main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/spinnerlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/filter_array"
            android:prompt="@string/filter"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/listlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/loglist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notify method is called repeatedly real quick and my list is updating quite fast due to behaviour of the process. When i remove the update block of the code, click events of the spinner is active, but when the update block is active, events are not working. I thought this was a focus problem but i couldn't be sure, since i the menu is clickable. The problem is that when i select one of the items in the list, spinner is not selecting that item and keep the old selected value, and the event of the click is not working either. Ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: where you set your `adapter`? and how spinner get filled?

Comment: list.setAdapter(adapter); and spinner get filled from an array in Strings.xml, though I think neither adapter nor values in the spinner has anything to do with the problem here. As i told you, when i remove adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() i can capture the events.

Comment: Oh and one more addition, most of the time when i select a value in spinner, i see a log "eglsurfaceattrib not implemented". This might be my solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, i fixed my problem with adding these two settings to the spinner, i was sure i tried this before but oh well, android focus is still a half mystery to me.

```
        filterTypeMenu.setFocusable(true);
        filterTypeMenu.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: Oh my bad.. I was trying to stop update list with a flag to see if it was working. My click events are still inactive when list is updating. Flag control is working but that also brings another problem, since i cannot capture any events on spinner or even the layout around it, i can't change the value of the flag.